# How to toggle running Xcode project in debug or release mode by using only shortcut keys?

Tags: xcode

By default, to "run" my project in release mode, I need to edit the scheme's run settings to use "release" instead of debug.

To not have to edit the scheme each time I want to switch between debug and release mode, I created a new scheme which runs in release. But this is still tedious since I need to click on the relevant scheme if I want to switch.

Is there a way that I can automatically (build + run) in debug / release mode using only short cut keys ?

I don't wan't to profile! Because that launches instruments etc.

EDIT: To be clear - I'm always running on the device.

Comment: I need a way to switch between debug and release mode quickly, ideally using only shortcut keys.

Comment: This bothers me so much. I really like Visual Studio's drop down for selecting the build configuration you want to use. My problem with Xcode would be solved if I could change the default build configuration for "Run" to "Release."

Answer (score 43):

Debugging build: "Product" Menu  => "Build For" => "Running" (shift-command-R)

Release build: "Product" Menu => "Build For" => "Profiling" (shift-command-I)

Run without building (whichever you just built): "Product" menu => "Perform Action" => "Run without building" (control-command-R)

Comment: That doesn't achieve my objective. Suppose I just finish running and installing the binary on my iOS device using shift+cmd+r. Then doing shift+cmd+i , followed by ctrl+cmd+r, doesn't replace the debug build on my device with the release build. Did I misunderstand your answer ?

Comment: No; you never mentioned anything about "installing the binary on my iOS device". I answered the question you asked (about Xcode).

Comment: Using "Build for Profiling" followed by "Run without building" runs in Debug mode (not whichever one you built).

Answer (score 20):

The equivalent in XCode that you seek is the "schemes".

Right of the play/stop buttons, there a pretty handy scheme selector. You just need to create a scheme for debug and another for distribution.
[image]

[image]

In order to make a scheme for debug or distribution, simply go to the scheme configuration (either selecting "edit scheme..." or "new scheme...") and choose the correct build configuration under "Run -> Build Configuration":
[image]

Note: I have XCode 9.1, I don't know if this is valid for older versions.

Answer (score 17):

There is one way that I use it for my projects.

In Xcode, go to the the project settings (project, not target) and add "beta" configuration to the list:

[image]

Then you need to create new scheme that will run project in "beta" configuration. To create scheme go here:

[image]

Name this scheme whatever you want. The you should edit settings for this scheme. To do this, tap here:

[image]

Select Archive tab where you can select `Build configuration`

[image]

Then you need to add a key `Config` with value `$(CONFIGURATION)` the projects info property list like this:

[image]

Then its just the matter what you need in code to do something specific to beta build:

```
let config = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "Config") as! String
if config == "Release" {
  // app running in release configuration
}
else if config == "Beta" {
  // app running in beta configuration
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In XCode 7 you can switch between schemes using the shortcut: control-command-right/left bracket (select next scheme, select previous scheme).  So I think creating two schemes is your best bet.

BTW, for everyone asking why one would do this - If you are writing a high performance piece of code you will find yourself constantly switching between release and debug mode for a lot of reasons.  Release mode (especially in swift with whole module optimization on) takes forever to build and optimization changes stack traces, etc.