# React Native Reload and Dev Tools Do Not Work

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

*TL;DR – My React Native project runs/renders successfully. The reload or developer tools on device shake abilities are not working.*

---

I've setup React Native within an existing project following [this guide](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/react-native-in-an-existing-ios-app-delivered-874ba95a3c52#.pd66reyfp). I am able to successfully render my React Native views with the following:

1. In project root: `(JS_DIR=pwd/js; cd node_modules/react-native; npm run start -- --root $JS_DIR)`
2. Build and run the project within Xcode

However, once the simulator is running I cannot use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to reload the JavaScript, nor am I able to use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to display the developer tools.

I did not use `react-native init <ProjectName>` to create the project. I am adding React Native to an existing Swift project. I am not using `react-native run-ios` as it throws the following errors:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Local-iphonesimulator/FXBlurView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FXBlurView.o FXBlurView/FXBlurView/FXBlurView.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Local-iphonesimulator/FXBlurView.build/Objects-normal/i386/FXBlurView.o FXBlurView/FXBlurView/FXBlurView.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Local-iphonesimulator/FXBlurView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FXBlurView-dummy.o Target\ Support\ Files/FXBlurView/FXBlurView-dummy.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Local-iphonesimulator/FXBlurView.build/Objects-normal/i386/FXBlurView-dummy.o Target\ Support\ Files/FXBlurView/FXBlurView-dummy.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
/Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:464:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:484:13)
    at _runIOS (runIOS.js:91:34)
    at runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/Users/username/Sites/iOS/project-name/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:86:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.4/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

What should I look for to get the reload and developer tools abilities working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have custom configurations and you're using Cocoapods, make sure the `Podfile` specifies that those configurations should be `debug` configurations. By default they are assumed to be `release` configurations. Add the following line to the top of your `Podfile` (assuming your custom configs are "Dev", "Local", and "Staging"):

For pre-1.0 Cocoapods use [`xcodeproj`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#xcodeproj):

```
xcodeproj 'MyProject', 'Dev' => :debug, 'Local' => :debug, 'Staging' => :debug
```

For Cocoapods 1.0+ use [`project`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project):

```
project 'MyProject', 'Dev' => :debug, 'Local' => :debug, 'Staging' => :debug
```

Then, to get the `Pods.xcodeproj` file to update:

```
rm -rf Pods/
pod install
```

This will ensure the `DEBUG=1` Preprocessor Macro is set for those configurations for the `Pods` project.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out if your [Build Configuration is named anything other than "Debug"](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6011), then reload and the dev menu is not available. [Renaming the Build Configuration back to "Debug"](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5122#issuecomment-205708298) resolved my issues for the short-term.

This seems like a bug with React Native, but there doesn't appear to be any movement on fixing this "issue" within the library.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to resolve this issue with custom Build Configuration names?

Comment: @koxon I solved my issues with the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say it looks like you're running your app in release mode. That's when Reload and dev tools are disabled. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897728/how-to-toggle-running-xcode-project-in-debug-or-release-mode-by-using-only-short) to see how can you switch between release and debug mode.

Also, if you followed the guide you mentioned, in order to hit the dev server, make sure the variable  BOOL REACT_DEV_MODE is set to YES, otherwise you will always use the local bundle instead of the dev server.

> BOOL REACT_DEV_MODE = YES;

After that, make sure that when you navigate in your app to your RN view, you see a request from your app hitting the local server (in your terminal) just like this:

[image: local server]

BTW, It's expected for react-native run-ios to not work if you're adding it to your react native project. That command will work only for full RN apps.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you. From the tutorial, I do have `let REACT_DEV_MODE = true` at the top of `func initializeReactView`. Also, my RN view is hitting my local server. My Terminal shows the output you described when I load the view.

I had not used release-specific build commands before. After reading the thread you linked, I used "Build for Running" and "Run without building", but to no success.

In the simulator, I also have "Connect Hardware Keyboard" enabled. I also attempted running on a connected iOS device and shaking.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: What version of RN are you using?

Comment: RN 0.24.1 and React 0.14.8

Comment: The server does not change/output whenever I save a JS file. Should it?