# Swift: Debug mode not working on Test flight

Tags: swift, xcode

in my project I have code surrounded by marks of DEBUG mode `#if DEBUG` like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    let goToMainScreensGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(navigateToMainStoryboard(_:)))
    goToMainScreensGesture.delegate = self
    goToMainScreensGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    logoLargeImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    logoLargeImageView.addGestureRecognizer(goToMainScreensGesture)
#endif
```

But that does not work, is there another alternative to add my own debug mode?

On TestFlight, Apple is automatically moving Debug mode apps to Release mode.
I need to add my own global debug mode to the app for the debugging features to work.

What is the best practices on how to do this right?

Comment: In the project, in which scheme is that macro set, and when you release on TestFlight, which one do you use?

Comment: Scheme debug mode

Comment: But when you release on that Testflight, what the scheme used? For instance, you can use Debug, Beta and Release. Allowing some new feature on beta.

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: Check the on the Archive what scheme it use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897728/how-to-toggle-running-xcode-project-in-debug-or-release-mode-by-using-only-short (to get how find it).

Comment: In project info there is "use release for commande line build" I must to switch it to  "use debug for commande line build"?

Answer (score 1):

Imho, most useful is to create your own custom `info.plist` variable and check it at runtime. If your debug mode doesn't contain secure data.
Otherwise, you can use 'other linker flags' which depends on your target.