# How to compile in Release Mode on MacOS XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, adobe, release-mode

I have developed some Adobe plugins for PC and successfully compiled them in release mode using VSC++. Now I'm attempting to do the same on Mac - compile them for MacOS, using XCode 11.

I have done a lot of research but I still can't get an official answer. I want to make sure I am compiling in release mode as opposed to debug mode for distribution.

This thread says to do so by selecting **"Product" Menu => "Build For" => "Profiling"** - [How to toggle running Xcode project in debug or release mode by using only shortcut keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897728/how-to-toggle-running-xcode-project-in-debug-or-release..).

This thread says (and a few others) to select **"Product => Archive"** It seems to be for IOS but probably applies to MacOS as well - [How do I create a release build in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706548/how-do-i-create-a-release-build-in-xcode)

Finally, this thread (and several others) say to **Edit the Scheme** - https://pinkstone.co.uk/deploying-your-app-from-xcode-to-a-device-with-release-build-configuration/

As you can see there is a lot of conflicting information. I have been following the first thread and selecting "Product" Menu => "Build For" => "Profiling". I distributed the plugin to some testers and it worked on their machines. But I want to be 100% sure, especially for the speed gain in release mode.

Could someone please offer some guidance to this so that we have it clearly answered for all?

Also, is there a way to check if your compiled project is in debug or release mode once compiled?

Thanks in advance,

-Richard

Comment: What Adobe product is the plugin for?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5706800/4641116

Comment: It's for After Effects. The link you provided says you must use the archive method to produce a release build. So the other two methods won't produce release builds?

Comment: I don't see where it says to use an archive method.  It says to edit the current scheme and for Build Configuration choose "Release".

Comment: Also the After Effects webpage has a link to its plug-in documentation: https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/aftereffects.html

Comment: The link you provided regarding release mode is for compiling for IOS, whereas I am compiling for MacOS. Does that matter?

Comment: And I'd still like to understand why there are three different methods of compiling for release mode (as pointed out in my message according to the different threads), and which are correct / incorrect.

Comment: *Product > Archive > Export > Save for Ad Hoc Deployment ...* is creating an **ad hoc deployment** (i.e., is suitable for internal distribution within your company).  *Product > Build For > Profiling* is creating a symbolicated build that is suitable for **profiling** purposes.  Editing the scheme for the Build Configuration **Release** is for creating a release build.

Comment: Hi Eljay - I tried to follow your directions tonight. I went to Project -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and under Build Configuration, where it says Debug, I tried to change it. But there is no other option. It only has 'Debug' in there. What am I missing?